# Error on “pod setup” command on my terminal(Cocoapods Installation)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode6, cocoapods

I successfully installed cocoa pods on my mac and i got message on my terminal like this..

> Successfully installed cocoapods-0.33.1
>    Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.33.1
>   1 gem installed.

After this i run following command (MacBook-Pro:~user$ pod setup) on my terminal then i got error message like this.

> Setting up CocoaPods master repo
>   [!] /usr/bin/git clone 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' master --depth=1
>   xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change.

How to solve this issue?Please help me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the path to your version of Xcode is broken. You can see what the path is set to with:

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

You will probably see the `/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` which must not exist. You'll want to set the path with:

```
xcode-select --switch /path/to/xcode
```

Comment: i got error like xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/path/to/xcode'

Comment: You need to replace `/path/to/xcode` with the actual location of Xcode.app

Comment: Oh "user". You gave me my laugh for the day.

Comment: @KeithSmiley,Thank you so much....Absolutely you are great....Also thanks for well reply for my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change xCode path with below command in terminal:

sudo xcode-select --switch xcode_folder_path